# display current dates hours and minute

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-parsing

I am facing an issue in javascript dates. i want to do `minutes` and `second` from current date.

My code:

```
date = new Date();
currentdate = new Date();

newCurrent = GetFormattedDate(currentdate);

GetFormattedDate(date) {   
  hour =  ("0" + (date.getHours())).slice(-2);
  min =  ("0" + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
  return  hour + ":" +  min;    //output 18:43
}
```

expected output:

```
`18:00` //if minutes are 0 to 29 then show current hours reset the minutes again start with 0 like 18:00 

`18:30` //if minutes are 29 to 59 then show current hours reset the minutes again start with 30 like 18:30
```

What should I do? anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var myTime = d.getHours() +':'+ (d.getMinutes() <= 29 ? '00' : '30') ;
```

template string:

```
const d = new Date();
const myTime = `${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes() <= 29 ? '00' : '30'}` ;
```

or

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var altedMinutes = minutes <= 29 ? '00' : '30';
var displayTime = hours + ':' + altedMinutes;
```

If you want PM/AM

```
var suffix = 'AM' 
var hours = now.getHours()
if (hours>11) {
 hours - =12;
 suffix = 'PM' 
} 
... 
var displayTime = hours + ':' + altedMinutes + ' ' + suffix;
```

Comment: thanks can you plz also add `AM and PM` in time [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324133/koop4)

Comment: it is giving an error [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324133/koop4)

Comment: `prevdate.getHours() +':'+ (prevdate.getMinutes() <= 29 ? '00' : '30') ;`

Comment: how should i edit in this line `pm or am` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324133/koop4)